# how can i delete rows id from the database

Tags: php, html

can somebody help me?

```
here is my php script... 

$req = mysql_query('SELECT id,  email, start_date, end_date, time_event, time_submitted,  payment_method, status FROM booking_members WHERE status="Canceled"');
while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))
$req1 = mysql_query('DELETE FROM booking_members WHERE id='$id');
while($dnn1 = mysql_fetch_array($req1))
{
<td class="left"><center>
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $dnn['id']; ?>"><img src="images/cross.png"></img></a>
</td></center>
```

how can i get the id from $dnn['id'] in order to delete rows?

Comment: you have  syntax error
`$req1 = mysql_query('DELETE FROM booking_members WHERE id=$id');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike Brant is exactly right; You should delete them without doing a lookup first.  But if you wanted to access the id, you'd use:

```
// ... PREVIOUS

while ($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {

    $delete_id = $dnn['id'];

    $req1 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM booking_members WHERE id='".$delete_id."'");

// ... CONTINUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just run the delete directly?

```
DELETE FROM booking_members WHERE status='Cancelled'
```

There is absolutely no reason to first select all the id's and then loop through them all deleting rows one at a time.

Comment: i need to delete a specific row not all deleting row

Comment: @user3303166 Your code example seems to show you looping through the select query results and deleting each by id (though it is unclear where `$id` comes from).

Answer (score 0):

```
while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))
```

Where is the { ?
And here:

```
$req1 = mysql_query('DELETE FROM booking_members WHERE id='$id');
```

If you want the id, of last query, you must do: $dnn['id'] and not $id ( or you set $id before)...
And, for include a HTML script, in PHP script, you must use echo or print or must close the tags php ( ?> )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a look up, and im assuming you are using dot net nuke, download the free reports module. After installing it edit it and type in the following select statement:

```
Select u.id,
u.username,
 u.email,
b.start_date,
b.end_date,
b.time_event,
b.time_submitted,
b.payment_method,
b.status
FROM users as u 
Join  
booking_members as b on u.userid = b.userid 
Where status="Canceled"'
```

this will show you the username, email, start_date, End_date, Time_event, Time_submitted, Payment_method and status of users where there status is canceled...